# How to use hebrew in HTML2PDF lib php?

Tags: php, right-to-left, hebrew, html2pdf

There are somebody who succeed to generate "HTML with hebrew text to pdf" with this library?
I got ???? instead of hebrew fonts
Didn't found any solution in web

Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Seems the question is off-topic .

Comment: I have the same issue, will update you with the solution soon

Answer (score 1):

Its long time since this question was asked I had to answer this because I had the same issue, and assume it will help others.
Usually when you see ? or squares instead of font chars it means the font is not includes
the language so you have to load another font which includes the lang, Hebrew font for the  HTML2PDF lib php will be

```
    require_once('html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
    try {
      $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en', TRUE, 'UTF-8');
      $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
      $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('dejavusans'); // dejavusans font supports hebrew
      $html2pdf->Output('order.pdf');
    } catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
      writeLog('ERROR creating pdf...' . PHP_EOL . $e);
      exit();
    }
```